# is it possible to address the column or row number that apply() is acting on in r

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame `final` that looks something like this

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 mCount   
1 D D R R D D R R R R  0    
2 R R D D D R D D R D  0    
3 D D R R D D R R D D  0    
4 R R R R D D R R R R  0
```

Every two columns should match. Notice how in row 2 however, there are a couple instances of adjacent columns not matching. My end goal is to count the instances of these non matching instances in the `mCount` column.

I have successfully done this using `for` loops

```
for(i in 1:10){ #cycle through columns
  if(i %% 2 == 1 %% 2){ #every other column
    for(j in 1:4){ #cycle through rows
      if(final[j,i] != final[j,i+1]){ #compare adjacent values
          final$mCount[j] <- final$mCount[j] + 1 #adjust mCount accordingly
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is do this without using `for` loops possibly using the `apply` function. My problem is I don't know how to address the columns that `apply` is working on in order to make the comparison.

Does anyone know how to do this or perhaps some other solution that would have the same result?

EDIT: I actually think I would be using the `rollapply` function but the question still stands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need either.

```
final <- read.table(textConnection("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 mCount   
D D R R D D R R R R  0    
R R D D D R D D R D  0    
D D R R D D R R D D  0    
R R R R D D R R R R  0
"), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,-11]
```

I think the trick is realizing you need to compare the odd columns with the even columns.

```
final$mCount <- rowSums(final[c(1,3,5,7,9)] != final[1+c(1,3,5,7,9)])
final
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 mCount
# 1  D  D  R  R  D  D  R  R  R   R      0
# 2  R  R  D  D  D  R  D  D  R   D      2
# 3  D  D  R  R  D  D  R  R  D   D      0
# 4  R  R  R  R  D  D  R  R  R   R      0
```

(You should be able to disregard the column names introduced by using `read.table` with numeric column names.)

As hard-coded, this is not very general, but it should not be hard to generalize it:

```
odds <- seq_len(ncol(final)) %% 2 != 0
final[odds] != final[!odds]
#         X1    X3    X5    X7    X9
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
rowSums(final[!odds] != final[odds])
# [1] 0 2 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution can be generalized for groups larger than 2:

```
m<-matrix(c( "D", "D", "R", "R", "D", "D", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "D",
             "D", "D", "R", "D", "D", "R", "D", "D", "D", "R", "R", "D", "D", 
             "R", "R", "D", "D", "R", "R", "R", "R", "D", "D", "R", "R", "R",    "R"),byrow=T,ncol=10)

# size of the group    
n=2
g <- rep(seq(1,ncol(m)/n),each=n)
find <- function(d)
{
    sum(sapply(split(d,g),function(d) nlevels(as.factor(d))-1))
}
t<-apply(m, 1, find)

data.frame(m,mCount=t)
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 mCount
#1  D  D  R  R  D  D  R  R  R   R 0
#2  R  R  D  D  D  R  D  D  R   D 2
#3  D  D  R  R  D  D  R  R  D   D 0
#4  R  R  R  R  D  D  R  R  R   R 0
```